# Hide Empty Document Properties in word 2013

Tags: 2013, word, document-template, quick-parts

I have a SharePoint document library with a custom document template attached to it. This document template is having lot of Quick part fields , which will pull metadata column values from the document library item into the word document.Everything is working fine in this functionality.My document is pulling data from the metadata columns. But no the issue is if the metadata property is blank the word document will show "[Column Name]" in the place where the value would have been shown if not blank.What i want to achieve is to hide those properties when the value is blank. I have followed this [Blog to hide Document properties](http://www.teylyn.com/articles/sharepoint-articles/hide-empty-sharepoint-metadata-columns-in-word-2010/) when value is blank.But this is not refreshing the value dynamically. ie it is working only if i download the created document and open the document and click F9 ie a manual process. 
All my documents are created through SP Designer workflow.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to have the document refresh itself automatically. The only option would be to save it as a macro-enabled document (.docm) and trigger the refresh from code on document opening

Comment: @MdMazzotti Does the macro enabled document have a client system dependency? Can you share any link if you have done this

Comment: a docm can only be opened by Microsoft Word 2007+ (but other sw like OpenOffice Writer might be able to open it; I've never tested it though).

Comment: @Unnie did you found a solution. I am stuck on the same issue

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to hide empty fields
[Check this blog](http://www.teylyn.com/articles/sharepoint-articles/hide-empty-sharepoint-metadata-columns-in-word-2010/)

Comment: Please consider adding some more details to your answer rather than posting link only answers. Once the link is broken your answer is of no use for community member.

Comment: this blog is the perfect answer. You are basically embedding your Quick Part into Field code and saying: IF [FIELD] = "[FIELD]" display "", else Display [FIELD]

Answer (score 0):

There is one way:
You can remove the placeholder text from Word's XML.

I have found out, that when you rename docx file to zip file and unpack to some folder, there are XML Folder\word\glossary\document.xml and Folder\word\document.xml

For each PlaceHolder (in glossary\document.xml) there is some XML Node (<w:docPart>), where you can find this elements <w:t>[State]</w:t>.

Same elements elements <w:t>[State]</w:t> look in document.xml.

When you remove "[State]" from this elements all document properties will be empty. Unfortunatelly all document properties...

```
    <w:docPart>
        <w:docPartPr>
            <w:name w:val="6B065C21091C4A3EB2ED303418489498"/>
            <w:category>
                <w:name w:val="General"/>
                <w:gallery w:val="placeholder"/>
            </w:category>
            <w:types>
                <w:type w:val="bbPlcHdr"/>
            </w:types>
            <w:behaviors>
                <w:behavior w:val="content"/>
            </w:behaviors>
            <w:guid w:val="{C72BE424-6B80-4344-9F1D-E3C0E8226E6B}"/>
        </w:docPartPr>
        <w:docPartBody>
            <w:p w:rsidR="00967279" w:rsidRDefault="008A1C99">
                <w:r w:rsidRPr="00EE3CA7">
                    <w:rPr>
                        <w:rStyle w:val="PlaceholderText"/>
                    </w:rPr>
                    <w:t>[State]</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:docPartBody>
    </w:docPart>
```

Comment: can you explain the procedures for it